# How to correct wrong DPI reported from getMetrics

Tags: android

I made one application - StribogECG, which display ECG and some other file types. 
There, I create background, which is "graph" paper, with points at every mm, doted lines at every 5 mm, and lines at every 25 mm. The problem is on some devices 25 mm are equal to 25 mm, but on other devices 25 mm are equal to 30 mm.

Then I made some calculations, and I found that device can report DPI=160, but actual size is 150 or even 133 for some tablets.

Acer Iconia Tab A500 is 10 inch and 1280/800.
What I have is:

```
metrics.xdpi = 160;
metrics.densityDpi = 160;
metrics.density=1;
metrics.scaledDensity=1;
```

In this case, diameter of device must be 9.4 inch, and if diameter is 10 inch, then DPI must be 150.

Of course I measured with normal measurement line, and instead of 25 mm I have 26.5 mm. And problem is much bigger on some 7 inch tablets.
In this moment, I can see only one solution - to ask user to make additional calibration - to print on screen two lines and to ask user to put second line on 50 or 100 mm away.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to inspect `metrics.xdpi` and `metrics.ydpi` to get an accurate density numbers.

Comment: Emphasis was on *and*. But for a 2.5 year old post, this is moot. OP is long gone.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you only know what the device tells you, and it is quite common for the DPI value to be set wrong. This is usually done as a hack to make the visual elements in the interface larger.

See this post for more details: https://rschilling.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/android-screen-density-inaccuracies/

If your application demands accuracy, you will need to add a manual calibration step.